# PDFtron sticky note label

Tags: javascript, pdf, annotations, pdftron, stickynote

Is there a way to add a label at the top of sticky note similar to the image below? Other than adding and grouping a text with the sticky note.

[image: Sticky note with label]

```js
if (action == 'add') {
  for (const annot of annots) {
    if (annot instanceof instance.Core.Annotations.StickyAnnotation) {
      const label = new Annotations.FreeTextAnnotation(Annotations.FreeTextAnnotation.Intent.FreeText, {
        X: annot.X,
        Y: annot.Y - 15,
        TextColor: new Annotations.Color(0, 0, 0),
        StrokeColor: new Annotations.Color(255, 255, 255, 0),
        Width: annot.Width,
        Height: 15,
      });

      label.setContents(annot.Subject);
      instance.Core.annotationManager.addAnnotation(label);
      instance.Core.annotationManager.redrawAnnotation(label);
      instance.Core.annotationManager.groupAnnotations(annot, [annot, label]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported feature by the PDF spec by default, however you are using Apryse WebViewer so there are ways to make a similar behaviour.

Step 1:
Create your note annotation

Step 2:
Create your label as a FreeTextAnnotation: https://docs.apryse.com/documentation/web/guides/annotation/types/FreeTextAnnotation/

Step 3:
Group these annotations together via: https://docs.apryse.com/documentation/web/guides/annotation/annotationmanager/grouping#reading-grouped-annotations

Since this is an unsupported behaviour, and is a customized behaviour its not guaranteed to work in other PDF viewers, however if you only view PDFs in WebViewer it should be fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, this is my initial solution